# Getting common array values from array.map() in React

Tags: reactjs

For example, I have array:

```
    [{subject:"farm",name:"John Doe"},
     {subject:"steam",name:"Michael Buck"},
     {subject:"geo",name:"Ron Ruckle"}, 
     {subject:"geo",name:"Ben Bond"}];
```

And this code would do the trick to fetch all names:

```
{user.map((item,key)=>
   { return
      <tr key={key}>
       <td>{user.name}</td>
      </tr>
 })}
```

I want to fetch only those usernames who have subject="geo". How can I do it?

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `.filter()`:

```
{users
  .filter((user) => user.subject === 'geo')
  .map((user, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>{user.name}</td>
  </tr>
)}
```

Or return `null` inside your map:

```
{users.map((user, index) =>
  user.subject === 'geo' ? (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
    </tr>
  ) : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be as simple as this.

```
{users.map((user,key)=> { 
  if (user.subject === "geo") {
    return (
        <tr key={key}>
         <td>{user.name}</td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
 })}
```

Edited: Changed your variable names to be more proper

- `users` is the array of users. when we map each element in the `users` array is a `user`;

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use tables for coding your UI. Use `table` only for tabular displays. for everything else use `div`. Also, if you use a condition statement, you are forcing the DOM to evaluate every option in your array to be equal to "geo". In a small DB, no problme. When you have thousands or millions of values, not so great.

Better to programmatically filter through the prop before you send it to the DOM

Here's my option

```
export default function App() {

  const people = [
    {subject:"farm",name:"John Doe"},
    {subject:"steam",name:"Michael Buck"},
    {subject:"geo",name:"Ron Ruckle"}, 
    {subject:"geo",name:"Ben Bond"}
  ];
  
  const results = people.filter(obj => {
    return obj.subject === "geo";
  });


  const list = results.map((item) => {
    return (
      <p>{item.subject}, {item.name}</p>
  )})
  return (
    <div> {list} </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: There seems to be a misconception around when things are "sent to the DOM". Filtering and mapping in the function body vs inline in the returned JSX will make no performance difference unless the operations are also memoized. Both happen before anything is sent to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
{users.filter(user=>user.subject === 'geo').map((item,key)=>
      <tr key={key}>
       <td>{item.name}</td>
      </tr>
 )}
```